# Config Error The configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

> Config Error  The configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot
>   be read because it is missing a section declaration

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have a backup of the `web.config` from just before you started getting this error?

Comment: No...ihaven't any backup of web.config

Comment: Could you post the `System.web.extensions` section of the web.config file?

Comment: I'm also seeing a lot of people mentioning incorrect .NET framework versions configured on their sites. You should check that as well. http://forums.iis.net/t/1166889.aspx?The+configuration+section+system+web+extensions+cannot+be+read+because+it+is+missing+a+section+declaration